# Where could I get the rtm controller templates for asp.net identity?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, asp.net-identity, rtm

I know it's not open source (yet) but anybody know how to make the latest rtm packages work or perhaps a controller template that I can use to try it out?

It seems that it has changed significantly from the RC version.

Comment: I would love to get the latest RTM templates as well because there has been very significant changes to the Aspnet Identity functionality between RC and RTM

Comment: Vote this up so we can get some templates :)

Answer (score 1):

[RTM implementation sample](https://github.com/s093294/aspnet-identity-rtm)  by @s093294

I think someone else will be benefited by this answer after a long time.